# using same ad unit for interstitial and banner for ios and android

Tags: admob

I want to use the same Admob Ad unit for my android and iOS app
because I want to move all my app to the highest eCPM ad unit.

I read some posts that says it is OK to share the same ad unit for multiple app.

my question is :
If my ad unit is set for Banner. I use it for interstitial. Does it affect the eCPM ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For reporting sake, use different ad units for each app's banner and interstitial ad. This helps you know how each app is performing in regards to eCPMs, requests and clicks.

It will help you understand the market, adjust or improve your apps as needed.

It's not against the policy if that's what you want, but note that if you use the same ad unit for multiple apps and you link them to the play store, house ads might not work.  [Check this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/gNZ6xD0IXw8/x6axuJEmXK8J)

Answer (score 1):

If you set your ad for banner of course it affects CPM since interstitials especially if they are rich media pay way more.

I don't think you can use iOS ad units for Android - technical limitations unless you have some web view type of app, in that case it might work. If Google finds out somehow, they might ban you since you're trying to get iOS eCPM for Android users.